# Force an entry in an array to be an integer in julia

Tags: type-conversion, integer, julia

In the julia code below, the first entry of a_b will be updated in a for-loop. However, I want it to always stay an integer regardless of what it gets updated to, because I get the error: "ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: invalid index: 7.0 of type Float64" when I do the final line of my code as it is currently written below (the 7.0 is because ultimately the j in which we terminally assign a_b[1] to is indeed 7.0).

How does one accomplish this? Is there a way to preset the types for the entries in an array analogous to how one can set types when you define a dictionary in julia?

```
        a_b = [0, 1.0]  
        for j in 1 : 7     
            if T_w[j] > a_w_comma_T_w[2] && T_w[j] < a_b[2]     
                a_b[1] = j  
                a_b[2] = T_w[j]
            end
        end
        println("This is a_b: ", a_b)

        T_prime = copy(T_w)   
        T_prime[a_b[1]] = a_w_comma_T_w[2]
```

I think the problem is that the second entry in the array is a float (which I want to keep), and so it makes the whole array a float. However, I'm still not sure how to fix it.

Comment: use a `Tuple{Int, Float64}`

Comment: can you add the code for `T_w` and `a_w_comma_T_w` ?

Answer (score 1):

For each element to have a separate type but also be mutable, you'll need something other than an Array. Don't have something off the type of my head that is indexed by integers, though. I normally go for mutable structs (accessed by fields) or separate variables that I keep independently type-stable.

You *could* do `a_b = Union{Int, Float64}[0, 1.0]`, though. Each element can be either an Int or a Float64 instead of being converted to only a Float64. And since the Union is small, the Union-splitting optimization results in little performance loss.

Answer (score 1):

You can narrow the element type when defining the `Vector` using the `T[]` syntax such as:

```
julia> a_b = Int[0, 1.0]
2-element Vector{Int64}:
 0
 1
```

Now you have a `Vector` of `Int`s  and mutating it will keep `Int` values:

```
julia> a_b[1] = 77.0
77.0

julia> a_b
2-element Vector{Int64}:
 77
  1
```

Of course, rounding will not happen automatically:

```
julia> a_b[1] = 77.1
ERROR: InexactError: Int64(77.1)
```

Comment: They specify that they want to keep the second element as a Float. It's a strange choice not to use a struct or separate variables for this, but given that choice, BatWannaBe's Union suggestion seems to be what OP is looking for.

Comment: He uses `1.0` and talks about `7.0` so I am not sure :) As suggested earlier `Tuple{Int, Float64}` is perhaps the most obvious choice or `struct` could also do fine.

Comment: OP's code seems to be asking for something like `MutableTuple{Int, Float}` but can't find anything like it. I was guessing that when he said "j...is indeed 7.0" OP is thinking of the math value 7=7.0 rather than wanting j or a_b[1] as a Float64.

Comment: a `struct` in that case :)